Can batching help increase offline text-generation performance significantly?
I have a collection of documents, each <1k tokens. I want to evaluate each of them with a given prompt. My prompt is 330 tokens.
I have a Quadro RTX8000, which has 48Gb of memory, and 672Gb/s bandwidth. I'm running Meta-Llama-3-8b-Instruct-Q8_0 using llama.cpp and textgeneration-ui.
Currently, I'm loading 4 models (~40Gb) and sending each prompt + document to one of the 4 models. Each output is generated with about 10 tokens/s.
I want to speed up this process, and I'm wondering whether there's some way to batch my requests to increase the performance significantly. Is that the case? And how should I structure my system such that I can get better performance?

To speed up your document evaluation process using Meta-Llama-3-8b-Instruct-Q8_0 models on a Quadro RTX8000, consider batching your requests. Instead of sending each prompt + document individually to each model, batch multiple prompts and documents together. This approach leverages the GPU's parallel processing capabilities more efficiently.
You can structure your system to batch inputs in groups, then parallelize the processing across the available models. Ensure your implementation handles batching at the input level and manages GPU memory efficiently to maximize throughput. This method can significantly increase performance by reducing overhead and leveraging the GPU's parallel processing power effectively.

You've just reworded information from the question, and added fluff. This is a pattern across many of your answers. Are you machine-generating these?
